# Why is ShowGridLines so slow?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

I have noticed that enabling `ShowGridLines` on a `Grid` causes a huge performance hit.

I have a `Grid` within a `ScrollViewer`. When I scroll manually, the application runs fine. However, if I scroll programmatically, using a timer to scroll smoothly, it runs very slow with `ShowGridLines` on.

With `ShowGridLines` **off**, the scrolling completes in less than 1/2 a second as expected. With `ShowGridLines` **on**, the scrolling takes 2-5 seconds and jerks unpredictably.

Why would `ShowGridLines` cause such a performance penalty? Why would it not do so when scrolling manually? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ShowGridLines` property is not optimised for runtime as it is intended to be a design time tool only.

[From the documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines.aspx)

> Enabling grid lines creates dotted lines around all the elements
>   within a Grid. Only dotted lines are available because this property
>   is intended as a design tool to debug layout problems and is not
>   intended for use in production quality code. If you want lines inside
>   a Grid, style the elements within the Grid to have borders.

Comment: Interesting that it only blows up when I scroll via code. Thanks for pointing that out though!